# How do I close the file that Flask's send_file opened, but only after send_file has finished?

Tags: python, flask, file-handling

I'm trying to build a Flask app that converts certain files. The workflow includes receiving the original file, saving it to a temporary folder, running my file conversion code, downloading the new file using `send_file`, and then deleting all the files.

My problem is that `send_file` opens the new file but doesn't close it, preventing the file from being deleted. This is intentional behavior according to the [core developer of Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2468#issuecomment-331321836):

> People misunderstand the fact that `send_file` opens the file but doesn't close it. Other parts of the WSGI flow will close files after the response is built, so that things like streaming work.

But I can't figure out how to close the file so I can delete it.
`response.close()` will close the file, but will do so before send_file is completed, no matter how much of a delay I try to add inside the cleanup function. It appears that `time.sleep()` counts down, and then calls `send_file` while simultaneously closing the file that `send_file` has opened

```
@after_this_request
def cleanup(response):
    shutil.rmtree(absolute_folder_name)
    return response

return send_file(path_or_file=flask_output_filepath, mimetype="text/plain", 
                 as_attachment="True", max_age=None)
```

The `.close()` method for Flask's response class will close files open in the response object. But it does so before the response completes. Adding a delay with `time.sleep()` seems to only delay the start of the response, not waiting after the response is made.

I tried pulling

```
time.sleep(10)
response.close()
shutil.rmtree(absolute_folder_name)
```

out of the cleanup function and run after calling `send_file` directly like this:

```
response = send_file(path_or_file=flask_output_filepath, mimetype="text/plain", 
                     as_attachment="True", max_age=None)
time.sleep(10)
response.close()
shutil.rmtree(absolute_folder_name)
return response
```

But that didn't help.

Comment: Do note that `after_this_request` is not really after the request it's just to modify the response.

Comment: Is this answer related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483861/flask-delete-file-from-server-after-send-file-is-completed
Looks like the same issue to me.

Comment: @RajaSimon That's useful to know. Thank you

Comment: @EnsarSarajcic Same issue, but the answer isn't usable because after_request is global scope and other routes will break it file cleanup happens after a response

Comment: @Ashlynn okay, thanks. I guess that whatever the final response is, it is still good to have these linked, since I think that solution was not ideal for that question either.

Comment: @Ashlynn would something like this work then: https://tedboy.github.io/flask/patterns/deferredcallbacks.html
It still uses that `after_request` global function, but it makes sure to only invoke specific callbacks.

Comment: @EnsarSarajcic Unless I really fouled up the the implementation, that's still running into locked files. I asked this same question in the PyBytes community, and apparently it's just plain not possible. The only way to delete files used by send_file is to use some sort of task queue